# Documentation of a Covid booster shot for travel

Tags: paperwork, covid-19, vaccinations

I'm eligible for a booster shot in the US. Currently documentation here is a mess: You get the CDC health card, which anyone can photoshop in 20 minutes. Most of the documentation is done by the providers: My provider issued a PDF certificate and and a digital smart health card (which very few apps can read) and I managed to get mine transcribed into a EU certificate as well. My original provider doesn't offer booster shots, so I need to go to a different one: they will not be able to combine my records.

Chances are that booster shots will soon be required for travel as well. Given the flood of fake vaccination records in both the US and Europe we'll probably see a tightening on security requirements and a simple hand written card seems to be the absolute worst in terms of security

There has been talk about international travel or vaccination passes that would make life for airlines and passengers a lot easier.  Are there any of these already in existence? Are there any expected to come online soon and does any of these have potentially provisions for documenting boosters as well?

Any other tips or tricks how to handle this efficiently would be appreciate: main goal is ease of use, wide acceptance and reliability. I don't care about privacy.

Comment: There seems to be quite a long-ish list of airlines trialling the IATA pass https://www.iata.org/en/youandiata/travelers/iata-travel-pass-for-travelers/ and the EU Digital COVID Certificate (DCC), the UK NHS COVID Pass can be uploaded https://www.iata.org/en/pressroom/2021-releases/2021-08-19-012/

Comment: A few weeks ago I received a Moderna booster here in California. The provider (different from the provider of my initial doses) issued me a new CDC card that contains both the info from the original doses as well as the booster info. The provider (operated by the County) reported the booster to the California state database, which correctly updated its data within 24 hrs and now shows the initial doses and the booster, along with the state-issued QR code to access my record.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131441/discussion-on-question-by-hilmar-documentation-of-a-covid-booster-shot-for-trave).

Comment: @Hilmar can you describe how did you get the EU certificate if you didn't get vaccinated in EU?

Answer (score 2):

> There has been talk about international travel or vaccination passes that would make life for airlines and passengers a lot easier. Are there any of these already in existence? Are there any expected to come online soon and does any of these have potentially provisions for documenting boosters as well?

Yes, e.g. https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/news/lithuanias-eu-covid-19-vaccine-certificate-for-travel-to-be-updated-to-include-third-doses/:

> The European Union Digital COVID Certificate issued in Lithuania has been updated to include the third dose of a COVID-19 vaccine, administered as a booster shot.

Comment: UK looking at updating the NHS app too, albeit a change is said not to be imminent, which possibly means it’ll happen soon :-) https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/travel-booster-jab-government-vaccine-b1953447.html

Comment: In Germany, EU certificates are also issued for the booster shot (shown as 3/3 for types that requires 2 for the original treatment).